Continuity of a linear transformation on infinite dimension
Let $X$ be the vector space of convergent sequences of real numbers and consider the sup norm
$$
||(x_{n})|| = \text{sup} \{|x_{n}| : n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
Define $T: X \to X$ by
$$
T((x_{n})) = ((x_{n+1}-x_{n}) \cos n)).
$$
Show that $T$ is well-defined, linear and continuous.
I´ve already proved that $T$ maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences and that it is linear. To show that $T$ is continuous I know that I have to find a constant $M >0$ such that $||T((x_{n}))|| \leq M ||(x_{n})||$ for every $(x_{n}) \in X$. Now, if I expand on the left-hand side of the inequality I get
$$
||T((x_{n}))|| = ||(x_{n+1}-x_{n})\cos n|| \leq ||(x_{n+1}-x_{n})|| = ||(x_{n+1}) - (x_{n})||
$$
where the inequality comes from the fact that the cosine function is bounded above by 1. The thing is that I´m a bit stuck from here. I´ve thought about using the fact since $(x_{n})$ is a convergent sequence, the sequence $(|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|)$ converges to zero, but I don´t see how that is going to get me the inequality I´m looking for. Could someone give me a hint?

To show the boundedness of $T$: Let $x=(x_{n})\in X$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
|(Tx)_{n}| & = & \left|\left(x_{n+1}-x_{n}\right)\cos n\right|\\
 & \leq & |x_{n+1}|+|x_{n}|\\
 & \leq & 2||x||.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $||Tx||=\sup_{n}|\left(Tx\right)_{n}|\leq2||x||$. This
shows that $||T||\leq2$.
